# What is the term for a collection of a species of animals?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

For example, "demonym" is the term for the people from a place. Is there a term for describing the collective noun of a species of animals, like a business of ferrets, swarm of bees, or congress of baboons? Say I was making a table with the animal in one column and the collective noun as the header of another column. What would the header of the collective column be?

Comment: You don’t like: “Collective Noun”?

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/yussny/collective-nouns-of-animals-1?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYvOO4qO_aAhUGk1kKHf3gAvMQ9QEIDjAA